# Does movl maintain original value of source register?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

Note Intel x86.

After movl is called on a register, say like:

```
movl    %eax,-8(%ebp)
```

Is the original value of %eax still in %eax or only at -8(%ebp) in memory?

Comment: The source register is not affected by the move. You can get all the details in the [programmer's guide](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.html).

Comment: `mov` is more like a copy, so it doesn't modify the source in any way.

Comment: Well, the very first sentence of the "Description" part for `MOV` in Intel's instruction set reference is _"Copies the second operand (source operand) to the first operand (destination operand)."_

Comment: The choice of the `mov` mnemonic instead of `cpy` for copy operations sometimes bugs me, too, since it incorrectly describes the semantics.  Once you get over the philosophical arguments, though, it's easy to type and starts with a different letter than the also-common `cmp` compare mnemonic.  The insn ref manual is careful to note when an operation leaves anything in an undefined state (usually flags), and it doesn't say anything like that for the src operand for any instructions.  "data movement" is a common term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mov instructions do not change the source at all, so the short answer to your question is "Yes". The original value of %eax is still in %eax as though nothing happened.